# My MacBook's trackpad and keyboard do not work after startup

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, trackpad

**My MacBook:**

- MacBook Air 2014
- macOS Catalina 10.15.6

**My Problem:**

Two weeks ago my internal keyboard and trackpad suddenly did not work any more. The next day I restarted my computer and they worked again but only for a couple of minutes.

**This is what I found out:**

- I can NOT use my trackpad and keyboard after startup.
- I can NOT use my trackpad and keyboard on the login screen.
- I can NOT use my trackpad and keyboard after booting into Safe Mode by pressing down <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> during startup.
- I can NOT use my trackpad and keyboard after booting into Recovery by pressing down <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> during startup.
- I can use the <kbd>⦿ Power</kbd> button to switch my MacBook on or off.
- I can shut down my MacBook by pressing down <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> + <kbd>^ Control</kbd> + <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd> + <kbd>⦿ Power</kbd>.
- I can start up to the Apple Diagnostics utility by pressing  <kbd>D</kbd> during startup.
- I can start up to Startup Manager by pressing <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd> during startup.
- I can use my trackpad and keyboard in the Apple Diagnostics utility.
- I can use my trackpad and keyboard in the Startup Manager.
- *System Preferences → Trackpad* shows "No trackpad found".

**This is what i already tried to fix my problem:**

- I tried to reset my SMC by pressing <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> + <kbd>^ Control</kbd> + <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd> + <kbd>⦿ Power</kbd> for 10 seconds when my MacBook was turned off.
- I ran the Apple Diagnostics utility (by pressing <kbd>D</kbd> during startup) but it did not find any problems.
- I reinstalled macOS Catalina via macOS Recovery after pressing down <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> during startup.
- I replaced the Touchpad Ribbon Flex Cable that connects the touchpad with the main board

**Question:**

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: can you tell the battery level in the mouse?  It may need to be charged.

Comment: @jmh There is no problem with a mouse – it's the trackpad and the keyboard that do not work. At the moment I use a Apple bluetooth keyobard and a Microsoft USB mouse instead.

Comment: Yes I meant keyboard. Sorry.

Comment: Boot into [Safe Mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201262) (Hold `Shift` while booting).  The fact that it works in Diagnostics and not when macOS indicates that *something* is being loaded that causes the problem.  Boot to Safe and test out the keyboard trackpad, post your findings; do so with an [edit] to the question.

Comment: @Allan Updated my post with "I can NOT use my trackpad and keyboard after booting into Safe Mode by pressing down `Shift` during startup"

Comment: I updated my post with this: `System Preferences` > `Trackpad` shows "No trackpad found".

Comment: does the keyboad work?  Did you configure your track pad in system preferences to ignore the track pad?  One last test is to try this in Recovery as well. *Don't* have any external keyboards/mice plugged in.

Comment: @Allan Both the keyboard and the trackpad do not work after startup. I did not change any trackpad configuration for the trackpad in system preferences in the last months.

Comment: are you reiterating what you said or confirming that they don't work in the modes I asked you to test in?

Comment: @Allan I reiterated what I already wrote. But i just booted into Recovery where my internal trackpad and my internal keyboard do not work. Recovery asks me to switch on a bluetooth mouse and a blue keyboard. I then switched on my bluetooth keyboard and plugged in my USB mouse – both of which worked from then on. But my internal keyboard and my internal trackpad do not work in Recovery.

Comment: That's what I need to confirm.  You're top case is failing or has failed.  it needs to be replaced.

Comment: @Allan Do you have an explanation why the keyboard and trackpad work in the Apple Diagnostics utility and Startup Manager but not after the startup completed?

Comment: I don't know why this is the case, but I've seen it several times before and the fix was to replace the top case.  From a hardware perspective, everything works so it should work in macOS.  But, Safe Mode and Recovery give you "pristine" versions of macOS (like reinstalling) so it should work there.  The only fix was to replace the hardware.